# How to get keyboard shortcut `Cmd + S` to save on VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I attempt to save my file on Visual Studio Code with the `cmd+s` keyboard shortcut, it does not save the code. I have to manually click `File`, the `Save`, just to be able to save my progress. I'm using `macOS Catalina version 10.15.7` and `VC Code version 1.55.2`.

How do I fix this?

Attempts:

-Checked if `⌘ Cmd + S` keyboard shortcut is tied to the `Save` functionality

- [image: Keyboard Shortcuts]
- [image]

Answer (score 2):

---

### If you do it right this solution will fix your issue.

---

I have never had a problem saving with VS-Code personally, but I have had issues with keybindings. IDK if you write your own keybindings, but if you do, you might want to check the keybindings that you have wrote to make sure they do not conflict with **[CTRL + S]**. The *`keybindings.json`*  file that you create custom keybindings in, overrides the default *`keybindings.json`* file that defines the keybindings that VS-Code ships with.

To check your keybindings.json file...

- ###### Hit the `F1`-Key
- ###### A menu will drop open type in "Keyboard Shortcuts"
- ###### There will be two `Preferences: Keyboard Shortcuts`
- ###### Make sure to select `Preferences: Keyboard Shortcuts` and not `Preferences: Default Keyboard Shortcuts`

If the file is empty you are good. If you have keybindings written in the file, you need to iterate through them by hand, checking each one. Make sure that none use **[CTRL + S]** together. Even if the keybinding uses **[CTRL + S]** and other keys, you will need to disable it, so you can test if it is causing an issue.

---

#### Debugging [CTRL + S]

If your **`keybindings.json`** file is all good, then great, that's one thing to scratch off the list. The only thing left to do now is debug the Bound Key ("Key Binding"). To debug keybindings, you will use a built in tool, that VS-Code offers. To start do the following:

- ###### Hit the `F1`-Key
- ###### When the quick input drops open type the following into the text input:

  - *"Toggle Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting"*
  - Select the option: **`Developer: Toggle Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting`**
- ###### It should automatically open the OUTPUT panel, which is located in the same panel that your terminal is. Make sure that the OUTPUT is set to LOG(Window) in the drop down. (I took a picture and posted it below if you can't find the *Keyboard Shortcut Troubleshooter*).

###### *The image might have funny declensions because I am on a dual monitor setup with 1 1080x1920 curved screen and one 1080x720 screen...*. I cropped it to a STD HD 1920 width.

---

---

### I Got My Trouble-shooter working, and Output open, now What Jay?

---

Okay... Well your at the right spot. Now every-time you press some keys, you should see your ***OUTPUT WINDOW*** working like crazy. It should be logging all sorts of stuff, which is good, very good.

##### This Part Is Important! READ CAREFULLY

What you want to do is use your keybinding that you feel isn't working appropriately. Use it when focus is set on an editor, use it when focus is set on a different editor, use it when focus is set on the sidebar. Where you are focused at in the editor at any given time can greatly affect a keybinding. The output is gonna write lines every-time you use your keybinding. Try not to hit any other keys while doing this, so you have a column in you output that includes logging from the keybinding you are testing only. Read the output see what it says. See if it looks right, or wrong. If it looks wrong, you can visit this link, to the VSCode site that covers this topic, and see if you can fix it your self. If you can't fix it your self, come back here, and edit your question. When you edit your question make sure that it includes the **Troubleshooter's Logging Output**.

##### [VSCode Troubleshooting Keybindings (Keyboard Shortcuts) @ https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_troubleshooting-keybindings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_troubleshooting-keybindings)

---

### Image that shows how to open the Keyboard Debugger

###### *Also shows how to set the OUTPUT to `Log(Window)`*

---

[image: StackOverflow-2021-JUNE-26018:34-PST]StackOverflow-2021-JUNE-26018:34-PST

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I don't write my own keybindings

Comment: @ln09nv2 Were you able to fix the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Comment: What does the log say when you use the troubleshooter?

Comment: That's not good you didn't resolve the issue, bud. You need to fix it. Were you able to turn the troubleshooter on at all?

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to check for is, for lack of a better term, combination key bindings. For example, I was having an issue with ⌘+s. VSCode gave a message that it was waiting for the second key binding. After looking at the keybindings.json, I noticed I had a key binding for opening up user snippets as

```
  {
    "key": "cmd+s cmd+n",
    "command": "workbench.action.openSnippets"
  }
```

The ⌘+s portion of this key binding conflicted with the default ⌘+s